# Fetch complex JSON object with php

Tags: php, mysql, json, server-side

I have in my server side my `json` object in such format:

```
{"page_1":{
   "stats":{
      "s1":10, "s2": 20}
    },
   "rules":{
      "rule1":{
       "x": 2, "type":"normal"}
      "rule2":{
       //etc
        }
     }
  },
 "page_2":{
   //etc
  }
}
```

How can I get access to different element using `foreach` for example, because I need to save them into db.

UPDATE: I tried that but in vain:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo $key."\n";
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        echo $k." -- ".$v."\n";
    }
```

}

Comment: are you converting this from json string?

Comment: i already have it as string

Comment: you can use `json_decode($json_string,true);` and get it as php array.

Comment: Yes, I have use decode, how can I get access using that array?

Comment: @HoussemBdr please show the entire code from the point you definitely have a string to the point where it behaves unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
$myarr = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($myarr as $key=>$val){
    echo $key, '=>' ,$val , "\n";
}
```

You are working with normal PHP array here.

Your code modified (not tested)

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo $key."\n";
    echo "heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeere: ", $key['stats']['s1'] , "\n";
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        echo $k," -- ",$v,"\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [json_decode($str, true)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert the string into associative array. After that you can access the data directly.

See also: [PHP: Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)